# parameter of system() in linux C++,Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

when I call system() with a long string(and it contains some Chinese characters),

system() seems not to deal my parameter correctly.

e.g. what system() recieved was not the same with what I sent

```
//it based on Qt

void work(QString order)
{
   system((const char*)order.toLocal8Bit());
   // in terminal, it shows a wrong command different with what it should be.
}
```

and when i call

```
work( "g++ "+nfile+name+".cpp -o "+nfile+name+" 2>"+nfile+"compiler.out" );
```

nfile represents a **long** path with some Chinese characters

Comment: You should check system()'s return value, especially if you are calling work() inside a loop. Else, if the user hits ctrl+C, it will only kill the g++ process, and continue the execution of your program, which may call system again, so your program will be unkillable and will continue execution recklessly. See the wait()/waitpid() function to see how to unterpret what system() returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Qt, then its better to use `QProcess` rather than `system`, see [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html)

Comment: I saw QProcess::waitForStarted(int) ..is there any method that kills the process when using too much memory?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the string to UTF-8 and pass that to `system()`:

```
void work(const QString &order)
{
   system(order.toUtf8().constData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for toLocal8Bit()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit)

> The returned byte array is undefined
>   if the string contains characters not
>   supported by the local 8-bit encoding.

I'm assuming the Chinese characters you're using aren't supported. You may wish to try [toUtf8](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#toUtf8) instead.

Comment: @LX75249 "undefined" doesn't mean "won't work", it means "may or may not work as you expect and might do something completely different"